# Cannot include FFmpegMediaPlayer lib in my android project

Tags: android, android-studio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, decoding

I've to include in my Android studio project a lib for managing audio streams from urls. I'm tying to use [this](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer), but when I try to run the app and it reach the point where have to instantiate a FFmpegMediaPlayer object, it crush with the error

```
31444-31444/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

These the steps I've done to integrate the lib in my project:

- I've copied all .so, gdb.setup and gdbserver files from demo project and put them into my jniLibs replicating the exact folder structure
- I've copied fmp.jar from demo my libs forlder
- I've changed all paths in gdb.setup files accordingly with my project folder structure
- synch with gradle

I'm not an expert of Android specially for tasks like this, am I missing something important? If you need it I can give a test app

Thankyou

**Edit 1**

This is the complete error

```
08-19 10:20:42.066  31444-31444/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.example.lucabrognara.radiostreamprova.RadioActivity.onCreate(RadioActivity.java:126)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1892]:  1836 could not load needed library 'libswresample.so' for 'libavcodec.so' (load_library[1094]: Library 'libswresample.so' not found)
            at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:340)
            at java.lang.System.load(System.java:521)
            at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaPlayer.<clinit>(FFmpegMediaPlayer.java:604)
            at com.example.lucabrognara.radiostreamprova.RadioActivity.onCreate(RadioActivity.java:126)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it was sufficient read carefully the documentation:

> If you don't want to build the modules you can simple unzip the prebuilt ones and copy them to your projects "libs" folder

These the right steps:

- Create an android studio project
- unzip the prebuilt modules in jniLibs folder
- put the fmp.jar file in libs folder
- obviously include the android.permission.INTERNET in your manifest

Comment: Where is this fmp.jar file? Because from the project available on github, it doesnt exist.

Comment: I'm sorry but seems that the project structure is changed recently, so probably this instructions aren't usefull anymore. In the previous version the fmp.jar was in fmp-library/libs folder. Here https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer/tree/d2118537d08d37ca25a72ae6c808ecf6ed38d226 the repository before the last version, compatible with the instruction I've written